# Post date in MYSQL format

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting mm/dd/yyyy format dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624009/inserting-mm-dd-yyyy-format-dates-in-mysql)

Users are filling out a form for birthdate in this format MM-DD-YYYY.

I want to insert it into My SQL database in SQL Date format, YYYY-MM-DD.

What is the easiest way to change it? I considered doing a MID function, but was hoping to use something more efficient.

Thanks in advance!

***Yes this was answered before, but I was unable to find it, Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `my_database` (`my_date_field`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('".$my_date."', '%Y-%m-%d'));";
```

Comment: The question is definitely a duplicate of other stackoverflow posts.  I didn't think to search before posting my answer.