# mysql date format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know how to insert into column(of date type) date in the format of dd-mm-yyyy?

I'm using calendar, and it selects days like dd-mm-yyyy, but it can't be inserted because of the format that uses mysql by default (yyyy-mm-dd).

The problem is, that I need to compare dates that has been inserted by the calendar and the dates that has been automatically inserted with current_date function. Basicly I have column DoR (date_of_registration) and Status. I've made DoR of date type, and Status of varchar(). In the Status I use Calendar to insert the date. Thus, I've compared it anyway but it gives strange results. I guess it is not comparing correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Store dates in `DATE` datatype columns only. If you have dates in other formats, convert them and then store them. Comparisons should be easy then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting mm/dd/yyyy format dates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624009/inserting-mm-dd-yyyy-format-dates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the output from calendar into date format like this

```
$cal_date=17-08-2012;
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($cal_date));
echo $date; //gives date as 2012-08-17
```

Now you can insert this date into `mysql` and do comparisons

Comment: This kind of method I've used, thank you for the idea "to change the output from the calendar". I've used datepicker (jquery library) and inside I've just change the date format to: Date.format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'; and now everything is the same and I can compare dates ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
select str_to_date('31-12-2012', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

See [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

All you need are these two functions:

[`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

and

[`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Please, always store dates as a DATE type in MySQL. If you need to select it in another form, use the correct string function [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert database as dd-mm-yyyy. You have to user date format. If you are writing code in php you can parse date what every type you want

Select datetime for database. And insert date data `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` when you want to echo date different formats like

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2012-08-17 19:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is also another way to store the date like, if you are choose that

```
`<input type="date" name="bdate" />
`
```

> then it directly store the date in to database in yyyy-MM-DD Format.
>       Here my text field format is dd-mm-yyyy.
>    Here you don't have to convert the string using `strtotime()`