# java - hibernate - convert date from one format to another

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, datetime

I am trying to convert date from one format to another, the date entered is in this format : 'mm-dd-yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

I received the date from webpage in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format and when I insert this date in mysql using hibernate, the date changes to some anonymous value.

Please help !!! 
{

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class test{
public static void main(String...s)throws Exception{
Date date ;
String datestr;
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

date = dateFormat1.parse("01-01-2015");
datestr = dateFormat1.format(date);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(datestr);

date = dateFormat2.parse(datestr);
datestr = dateFormat2.format(date);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(datestr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this;

```
        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = originalFormat.parse("01-21-2013");
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

For Date type result;

```
    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse("01-21-2013");
    String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 
    java.util.Date dtt = targetFormat.parse(formattedDate);
    java.sql.Date ds = new java.sql.Date(dtt.getTime());
    System.out.println(ds);
    System.out.println(dtt);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

End the output is;

```
2013-01-21
Mon Jan 21 00:01:00 EET 2013
2013-01-21
```

Comment: thanks a lott but again here I will get the date in string , I want that string in Date type

Comment: Could you try last one, I 'm handling with type java.sql.Date

Comment: it worked , somewhat but when I used this input for Document Date : 2013-11-30 what the date got converted to : 2013-01-30

Comment: Oh sorry, you must use MM instead of mm, I editted the answer.

Comment: yes it worked, I changed it MM and it worked,  thanks a lotttt :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use this below code snippet

```
 public static String formatDate (String date, String initDateFormat, String endDateFormat) throws ParseException {

    Date initDate = new SimpleDateFormat(initDateFormat).parse(date);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(endDateFormat);
    String parsedDate = formatter.format(initDate);

    return parsedDate;
}
```

Comment: yes it will give me a string in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format, I know how to convert the string format to date also, but then how to convert this date which is in  'mm-dd-yyyy' format to the 'yyyy-mm-dd' date format which mysql wants

Comment: @Furquan now just chec kmy latest answer

Comment: yes, but then I want the date in DATE type object , is it possible or am I just wasting time

Comment: @Furquan you may look a similar question's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/624021/2749470)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date initDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2015-03-05");
System.out.println("initDate == "+initDate);
```

output ==>> initDate == Thu Mar 05 00:00:00 ICT 2015

Answer (score 0):

In HQL simple SQL function work :

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%d-%m-%Y')
```